# Finding the variance(x,y) using python

Tags: python, variance

This is the question,

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

def mean(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2

def variance(x, y):
```

i need to come up with a code such that variance(1,5) gives 4.

I was thinking of using variance = e(x^2) - [e(x)]^2 but i keep getting the message in python saying there is a missing positional argument:y.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
variance(1,5)
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 2, in variance
    return (mean(square (x,y)) - square(mean(x,y)))
TypeError: square() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting an error, post the full error and stack trace...

Comment: Also, you can just use `statistics.variance` or `statistics.pvariance` for the population variance...

Answer (score 0):

In `return (mean(square (x,y)) - square(mean(x,y)))` you pass two arguments (`x` and `y`) to `square`, but if you look at the definition of `square`:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

you can see that it only take a single argument, hence the error `square() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Note that you'll run into the same error in reverse as soon as you fix that: `mean` takes two arguments, but you're only providing one.

Since this looks like homework I won't provide the code for the variance, but hopefully this clears up the technical problem (you already seem to know the correct formula to implement).